# Selenium driver doesn't click on element sometimes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

currently i'm writing a web scraper that will work in infinite loop. It gets a page, searches for some buttons and clicks one of them. But sometimes it doesn't! I save a screenshot in case of some fail and it showed me that page didnt changed after button clicked.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "btn"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
```

I have bypassed this with a loop checking does we see that element still.

```
while driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@name = "Submit"]') != []:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "Submit"]').click()
```

But hope to find a root cause of this. What it could be?

Comment: Make sure that you wait (e.g. explicit wait) an appropriate amount of time before and after the click.

Comment: i think you need proper wait to load page? or use expected contidions?

Comment: Page loads successful and fully - I can locate any element i need. I used time.sleep to wait 2-3 seconds for some delay, but should i use some selenium wait functions or smth else?

Comment: @academica yes sleep is bad practice use selenium like `WebDriverWait(driver,1000).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name = "btn"]")))` then run click.

Comment: Otherwise if element wasn't loaded yet function `find_elements_by_xpath` would return `[]`. Does it? I guess the problem is in web driver

Answer (score 2):

I also faced a similar problem with my application. Clicking the element through action class worked for me.
Here is the sample code in Java:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("Your ID Here"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(webElement).click(webElement);
builder.perform();
```

If clicking with action class does not work, you can also try clicking element by Javascript.

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("Your ID here"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you tell which webdriver did you use?